# What olive is a good taste substitute for Kalamata?

Tags: substitutions, olive

I am aware that [wikipedia has a nice list of olive varieties including tastes (sometimes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive). However, I'd prefer a considered answer, so this is the place.

I'm looking to substitute based on taste, not looks, as my local supermarket has messed with its Kalamatas and I don't find them nice anymore.

Googling indicates Gaeta, Amphissa, Nicoise, but it's an ambiguous mess.

I use a vinegar + brine-cured variant. What is the closest taste approximation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flavor-wise Nicoise and Kalamatas are somewhat close, probably the closest most readily accesible substitute for most people.